# Is there any numerical application whose performance heavily depends on the division operation?

Tags: computational-physics, computational-chemistry, computational-biology

I am an undergraduate student majoring in computer science.

Recently, I am interested in the division operation, which is not directly supported by some architectures. While some architectures support division, the  performance is not very good.

Is there a typical application in which division performance is critical?

Comment: Most often code would be limited by the speed with which instruction operands can be fetched from memory (hence caches, etc.) So whatever application you are looking for, it must be something limited only by instruction execution, so having very few or extremely regular memory accesses, and also having next to no delays due to instruction scheduling (few or very predictable branches). I'm not sure I know such an application myself (you're probably not interested in something trivial like drawing fractals whose iteration has a division in it), but those are pretty narrow restrictions.

Comment: I could imagine that forming the explicit inverse of a small matrix (say, 3x3) contains as a significant part floating point divisions.

Comment: Molecular dynamics, in the computation of interactions inversely proportional to distance.

Answer (score 2):

Molecular dynamics, in the computation of interactions inversely proportional to distance. Other N-body codes may share this property, but it's often an explicit goal to minimize or eliminate explicit division for exactly the reason you've given.